# Initialising of class elements in vector

Tags: c++, initialization

I have the following code below. I'm wondering why my code works and prints 5 lines of zero. Shouldn't the members of Node be uninitialised?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
  int a1;
  int a2;
  double b;
  double c;
};

int main(){
  std::vector<Node> nodevec(5);
  for(auto s : nodevec){
    std::cout << s.a2 << std::endl; // prints 5 lines of 0
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Just to clarify my question, according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector, it states that "3) Constructs the container with count value-initialized (default constructed, for classes) instances of T. No copies are made." Since Node is a class, isn't it default constructed? Won't the default construction of a class like Node mean that its members are uninitialised?

Comment: No, the elements of a vector get *value initialized*, which in this case means the members are *zero-initialized*.

Comment: The quote is missing some crucial information. This link is more complere: [*value initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this `std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) you will see that the items in the vector will be initialized either with `Node()` or value-initialized. Both of these are equivalent for POD types and will value-initialize all the members in the structure, i.e. set all members to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The vector constructor will fill new elements with value-initialised objects. A value-initialised object of a type with no default constructor will have all numeric members initialised to zero.